# Swift viewForHeaderInSection not called upon reloadRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, reloaddata

I have one UITableView with two sections. When i try to reload particular cell then the section header is not getting called. Here is my code for reloading one cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if tableView == self.pastEvalTableView{
            if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0{
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                var indexPathArray = NSMutableArray()
                indexPathArray.addObject(indexPath)
                self.pastEvalTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 2), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
                tableView.endUpdates()
            }
        }
    }
```

When i write above line `viewForHeaderInSection`is not getting called. Here is code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if tableView == self.pastEvalTableView{
            var cell: Personcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("personcell") as! Personcell
            return cell
        }
        return nil   
    }
```

Comment: try reloadSections:withRowAnimation:

Comment: @suhit thank you for quick reply. I tried with reloadSections:withRowAnimation then viewForHeaderInSection is called but view is not staying on UI. I mean its showing for few seconds and the gone.

Comment: can you add some code, its hard to figure out from the description why the view is not visible after some time

Comment: @suhit I updated my question and added some more code. Please let me know iy you want some more code.

Comment: can you add viewForHeaderInSection code

Comment: @suhit please check the question. I have added code for viewForHeaderInSection also.

Comment: are you using xib or stroryboard for configuring the header view. from code i don't see anything which can cause the issue.